# Как в javascript проверить блок id/div на наличие текcта внутри?

Tags: javascript

мой код

```
var startBut = document.getElementById('startButton');
var right = document.getElementById('right'); 

startBut.onclick = function(){
    if(right.value==" "){
        alert("hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Берем `textContent`, отрезаем лишние пробелы по бокам и проверяем

```js
var startBut = document.getElementById('startButton');
var right = document.getElementById('right'); 
var notext = document.getElementById('notext'); 

startBut.onclick = function(){  
  if(right.textContent.trim() != ""){
    console.log("в блоке right есть текст");
  } else {
    console.log("в блоке right  нет текста");
  }
  
  
  if(notext.textContent.trim() != ""){
    console.log("в блоке notext есть текст");
  } else {
    console.log("в блоке notext  нет текста");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="right"> уке  </div>
<div id="notext">                                  </div>
<input type="button" id="startButton" value="go" />
```